# como puedo llenar un input file con un array

Tags: javascript, jquery

files que quiero llenar con otro array es decir que los arreglos que tenga el otro array se introduzcan a This.file este es mi codigo

```
let imagenes = [];
    

    $(document).on("change", "#add-new-photo", function () {

        
        console.log(this.files);
        const files = this.files;
        var element;
        var contenedor;
        var supportedImages = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];
        var seEncontraronElementoNoValidos = false;
         
       
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            element = files[i];
            
            if (supportedImages.indexOf(element.type) != -1) {
                createPreview(element);
            }
            else {
                seEncontraronElementoNoValidos = true;
            }
        }

         
           
           for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {//se recorre el for
              contenedor = files[x];//se guarda el array
              console.log(contenedor);
              imagenes.push(contenedor);//se insertan los arrays
             }
             
             console.log(imagenes);
             this.value='';
             this.file.replace(imagenes);
             console.log(files);

        });
```

El array imagenes es el array que quiero meter dentro de This.files ¿como puedo hacer eso? ya e probado con `.push` o `this.files=imagenes;` pero no me sirve de nada tambien use la funcion `.splice` dice que this.files no una funcion

Comment: No puedes modificar  la propiedad "files"  de un input type=file desde javascript.

Comment: ¿y con cual lenguaje lo puedo hacer con ajax o jquery?

Comment: Ajax o jQuery a las finales son javascript y tengo entendido que los navegadores no permiten que puedas desde javascript tener acceso al disco local. Si entiendo bien que eso es lo que quieres agregarles al input files archivos que no fueron seleccionados por el mismo input.

Comment: No es que no fueron seleccionado por el input, si no que con cada click que se hace en el input se borra lo que avías seleccionado por ejemplo si seleccionas  tres imágenes y luego haces click otra ves y seleccionas otra imagen las otras tres serán borradas y solo quedara la ultima imagen por eso esta el array imagenes porque hay guardo todas la imagenes seleccionadas para luego insertarlas en el input files pero no se como

Comment: Quieres ir añadiendo lo que van seleccionando, entonces, en el evento change los envías inmediatamente al servidor y mantienes la lista de lo que ya cargaste y así sucesivamente a medida que carguen las imágenes. Es más las puedes visualizar al finalizar el Ajax de carga. Ahora la verdad es que no si puedes mantener un array de files y luego ir enviando por grupos.

Comment: De hecho esa parte la tengo solucionada porque todo lo guardo en el array imágenes el problema lo tengo que no se como hacer que lo que se encuentra en imágenes se inserte el this.files no se que método o framework usar

Comment: De hecho esa parte la tengo solucionada porque todo lo guardo en el array imágenes el problema lo tengo que no se como hacer que lo que se encuentra en imágenes se inserte el this.files no se que método o framework usar

Comment: Quizá funcione esto: crea una variable de tipo FormData. En el  FormData vas metiendo los archivos que desea: data=new FormData(); data["nimbrearchivo"]=files [n]; Esta variable sería como tú arreglo y lo puedes usar inclusiva para enviarlos al server vía Ajax. Otra forma no sé si hay, aparte que no sé si va funcionar. Me avisas si lo haces. Ah y no creo que puedas agregar al input files. También podrías ir clonando el input dile por cada click .

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usando spread operator

const arregloNuevo = [...arregloOriginal];

No necesitas meter el arreglo nuevo en un ciclo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No se mucho de Jquery pero ¿intestaste usando setAtribute?
Creo que en este caso quedaria

$(documento).setAtribute('file' , imagen)

Donde imagen que es un array debería pasar a un string del estilo "imagen1.jpg , imagen2.webp , etc.."